# Laravel login only works first record from database

Tags: php, laravel-8

I cant login with user that is not first record/row from the table. Below is my login controller and `store()` is the method I use for checking the user data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'npk' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            DB::table('sso_sessions')->insertGetId([
                'token' => $request->session()->get('_token'),
                'npk' => $request->npk,
                'login_time' => Carbon::now()
                ]
            );

            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
        return back()->with('loginFailed', 'Login Failed! NPK or Password is wrong!');
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('sso_sessions')->where('token',$request->session()->get('_token'))->update([
            'date_deleted' => Carbon::now()]);

        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

And below is my `User` model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */

    protected $table = 'sso_employee';
    protected $fillable = [
        'npk',
        'password',
        'id_role',
        'fullname',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    // protected $casts = [
    //     'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    // ];
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        if($this->id_role == 1)
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

My teammate have same code as mine and got no problem with the login. Why mine only works with the first record/row?

Comment: What you want is not correct way to identify a user. because YOU SHOULD NOT INSERT MORE THAN 1 USER WITH SAME CREDENTIALS.

Comment: @HamidMoladoust there's no evidence that the OP has done that